# Replacing default HttpClient for introspection in IdentityServer3

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 in a microservices based system that we are building to run on [Service Fabric on premise](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server/). I'm wanting to know whether it is possible to replace the HttpClient instance that is used to call the introspection endpoint from within one of our Web API stateless services.

With service fabric you have the ability to call directly to other services within a cluster but to do that you need to first query the service registry to find out the specific url for the service (it could be on any node in the cluster). There are patterns/classes to do this but you need to wrap retry loops around it in case the service moves to a different node, the node goes offline, etc.

The alternative is to call out to a load balancer / API Gateway which contains the lookup/retry logic but I'd prefer to not incur this extra hop if possible.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing it for the token validation you are referencing, and looking at the [options](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/blob/241051790c2bde4464c9bfa07325cc1b00c2c9ca/source/AccessTokenValidation/IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions.cs#L184) you indeed can set a `HttpMessageHandler` for doing the request.

You can then implement the SendAsync part of a messagehandler to change the url for which the request is being send.

Quick Example:

```
public class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Update the request url by replacing the base address to the internal endpoint.
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I did wonder if it was possible through the HttpMessageHandler but didn't seem obvious (to me!). I'll take another look at that approach and get back to you

Comment: Thanks for the example and pointing out this approach! I've managed to get it working with the following code:

Comment: I've managed to get it working using code based on your example and [service fabric docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication/). I can post a code sample but it's too long for the comments, what is the etiquette here? :-)

Comment: You just answer your own question with your code / example.

Comment: Ah ok, have posted example code separately. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Poul's answer I've managed to get it working with the following code:

```
public class CustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private static readonly FabricClient FabricClient = new FabricClient();
    private static readonly HttpCommunicationClientFactory CommunicationFactory = new HttpCommunicationClientFactory(new ServicePartitionResolver(() => FabricClient));

    public CustomHandler() : base(new HttpClientHandler()) {}

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var partitionClient = new ServicePartitionClient<HttpCommunicationClient>(CommunicationFactory, new Uri("fabric:/IdentityService/AuthApi"));

        return await partitionClient.InvokeWithRetryAsync(
            async (client) =>
            {
                //replace base address with resolved url of internal endpoint
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(client.Url, request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery);
                return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Note that the HttpCommunicationClientFactory, HttpCommunicationClient follow the pattern defined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication/).

I also had to configure IdSrv with [PublicOrigin](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityServerOptions.html) otherwise the JWT audience values are potentially different depending on which node the service is on.